# XGBoost in R: an error in the lengths of my matrix and Vector components

Tags: r

I am using (or trying to use) xgboost (in R) for the first time as I'd like to compare data science techniques. I have a dfataset I used to build a scorecard / PD model a few years ago and want to see how XGBoost performs on the same data

I use this code:-

keeps1 <- c("gb_estassval_woe","gb_prof_occ_woe","biztype_woe", "gb_educ_woe", "gb_region_woe", "gb_resstat_woe", "gb_leg_tel_woe", "gb_age_woe", "gb_TimeJob_woe", "gb_gender_woe", "gb_marstat_woe", "gb")
cc_dev1a <-subset(cc_dev_fin,,keeps1)

sparse_matrix <- sparse.model.matrix(gb ~ ., data =cc_dev1a)[,-1]

#gb is my 1,0 target variable

output_vector = cc_dev1a[,gb ] == "Marked"

str(cc_dev1a)
str(sparse_matrix)
str(output_vector)
head(output_vector)
#checking the number of records the output_vector has 57483, where sparse_matrix has 57157
#i thought the reduction may be due to na / missing value but can't find any (my variables are all processed to give a Weight of Evidence value, i.e. an integer

bst <- xgboost(data = sparse_matrix, label = output_vector, max_depth = 4,
eta = 1, nthread = 2, nrounds = 10,objective = "binary:logistic")

and get this annoying wee beastie of an error:-

Error in setinfo.xgb.DMatrix(dmat, names(p), p[[1]]) :
The length of labels must equal to the number of rows in the input data

please, what is causing it and how to i solve it.
thank you in advance

Comment: what give `dim(cc_dev1a)` and  `dim(cc_dev1a)` and  `dim(cc_dev1a[,gb ] == "Marked")` ?

Comment: thank you, I solved the issue (unconnected to the function)